# UISearchBar changes self.view frame

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar

I have added a `UISearchBar` with a `UISearchDisplayController` to a screen right under the navigation bar. When I tap on `UISearchBar`, it slides up to replace the navigation bar as expected. However, it leaves the underlying view resized and displaying a gap, like this:

[image]

This looks like room for a scope bar, but that is disabled in IB.

Also, when I log `self.view.frame` before and after the `UISearchBar` is activated, I see that `self.view.frame` position and height is modified by 44pt:

```
{{0, 20}, {320, 548}}
{{0, 64}, {320, 504}}
```

Any ideas how to fix this please? This doesn't happen in iOS6 by the way, only iOS7.

Here's how it looks in iOS6:

[image]

Comment: This might happen because of the scope bar that can be displayed when searching. Make sure to remove it with the `showsScopeBar` property.

Comment: As I mentioned above, it is unchecked in IB. I tried setting it to NO in code as well, but with no effect. This happens for iOS7 only though, no assumed scope bar placeholder in iOS6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found what was causing the black stripe under the `UISearchBar`. Apparently, this is a placeholder for a `scopeBar`, and the trick is in Interface Builder:

[image]

When you check the 'Shows Scope Bar' option for the `UISearchBar`, Xcode automatically adds 2 placeholder objects for scope button titles. However, when you uncheck the 'Shows Scope Bar' option, those placeholders are not removed. As long as you have more than 1 scope title in that box, `UISearchBar` will display a `scopeBar` under it. So the solution for me was simply to manually remove these 2 titles (leaving just 1 title also removed the black stripe).

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following line in the `viewDidLoad` to fix it.

```
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: I have done that already (with a check for iOS7), which actually fixed another problem I had of UISearchBar climbing on my status bar. However, the current problem persists even with this line...

Comment: Ok, got it. What do you want to achieve? Stop search bar from moving to the top of scale the view after the search bar moved up?

Comment: No, I want the view to start at the bottom of the search bar (as it does in IOS6) without that black gap between them

Comment: Have you had any thoughts since how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

UISearchDisplayController behavior seems to be quite buggy on iOS 7 in case your try to customize it (in particularly, customize searchResultsTableView). I'm not sure but, maybe, I had some similar issue.

Following code sample helped me:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    UITableView *searchTable = self.searchResults.searchResultsTableView;
    if (IS_IOS7 && searchTable.frame.origin.y != kSearchBarStartTopOffset) {
        [searchTable kSearchBarStartTopOffset];
        [searchTable setHeight:searchTable.height - kSearchBarStartTopOffset];
    }
}
```

kSearchBarStartTopOffset - is a start search bar offset within its superview frame:

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, kSearchBarStartTopOffset, 320, 44)];
```

Hope this helps, thanks